# How to pick from a set of random variables the one with the highest mean using a fixed number measurements?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, estimation, sampling

Suppose we have $N$ approximately normally distributed continuous random variables $X_1, X_2, X_3, \ldots,X_N$, each with an unknown mean and variance. I'd like to find the random variable with the highest mean.

Given a fixed budget of measurements $K$, how do I assign these measurements to maximize my chances of correctly picking the $X$ with the highest true mean?

Naively one could measure each $X, K/N$ times, then choose the one with the highest sample mean. Intuitively we ought to be able to do better by assigning less measurements to $X$'s with lower sample variance and/or lower sample mean (as they're less likely to be the one with the highest true mean).

**Is there an algorithm to produce an optimal sequence of measurement choices?**

Comment: Are the random variables independent? Presumably we can choose the $k$th measurement based on the outcomes of the previous $k-1$, correct?

Comment: You should look at the literature on *multiarmed bandit* problems, to which yours is closely related.

Comment: Thank, you cardinal! I assumed this was a widely applicable problem that must have been extensively studied before. However its name makes it somewhat difficult to search for if one doesn't know about ti already.

Comment: This [paper][1] compares several approaches for a very similar problem to mine, namely a pure exploration phase with a fixed number of arm pulls. However, it does not assume that the rewards are approximately normally distributed.




 


  [1]: http://imagine.enpc.fr/publications/papers/COLT10.pdf